# Firefox broken Ubuntu MATE

Tags: firefox, crash

My firefox refuses to launch even after a clean re-install. This happens with the taskbar shortcut as well as when launching through terminal `sensible-browser`.

It just gives me this Mozilla Crash Reporter [Terminal Error alongside Crash Reporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvyM5.png)

Any ideas?

PS Ubuntu is running on Raspberry Pi 3 and was confirmed working a few days ago

Comment: Try removing/backing up `~/.mozilla/` so you get a fresh new profile: `mv ~/.mozilla ~/mozilla.backup`. Also, would be interesting to see the output when you try starting `firefox` from a terminal emulator.

Comment: Here's the output: http://image.prntscr.com/image/1caaca07e7c44214ba61d6ab568a9290.png

Comment: And did you try with a fresh clean profile?

Comment: What do you mean a fresh clean profile? I never logged into it.

Comment: In your question you say "after a clean install", is that of the os or Firefox? If you just reinstalled Firefox, your user will still have a profile in ~/.mozilla/firefox which might contain an add-on or setting that is causing it to crash. Re-read my first comment.

Comment: see https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/firefox-55-0-2-doesnt-start-crashes-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberrypi-3/14637
(<https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/firefox-55-0-2-doesnt-start-crashes-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberrypi-3/14637>)
to resolve the problem.
best ~andreas

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox 57 still doesn't work!!**

From Firefox 55 through to 57, the same trouble continues, so this question is still valid. This issue only applies to Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu.

For those who need a working version and got as frustrated as I did, here is a workaround. There does not seem to be any way to fix this issue, except by downgrading Firefox.

You can use Synaptic to force an old version of Firefox, by selecting the Firefox package, then go to `Package` on the top bar, click `Force version` and click `apply`. Afterwards you must lock the package by going to `Package` and selecting `Lock version`. Note that you will only be offered Firefox 45.0.2.

You can also use apt from the terminal with something like:

`sudo apt-get install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1` (You can install other versions like this, you just have to get the build name exacly right)

Lock the version with

`sudo apt-mark hold firefox`

Alternatively, you could download the version you want from [here](http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/f/firefox/) and install it manually. Firefox automatically installs new versions, so you will have to disable this.